# Use time ,timeout and ulimit commands properly

Tags: bash, command-line, time, timeout

I'm running a command in CentOS and at the same time I want to do 2 things:

1. write the run time of the command to a file and
2. set a time limit which stops the command

I implemented the first one successfully. Here's how it is:

```
(time ./minisat+_64-bit_static opb_clauses.txt ) 2>>../measures.txt
```

As you can see, I used the time command to count the time needed by the command and then I forwarded the time results to a file `measures.txt`. Here's a sample of `measures.txt`:

```
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

I'm trying to add the second thing like this:

```
(timeout 1s time ./minisat+_64-bit_static opb_clauses.txt ) 2>>../measures.txt
```

The results of this command messed up my file and returned something like this:

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6368maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+440minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

As you can see, the results of the "real time" is somehow gone and the other results are in a different format. How can I separate the results of commands `time` and `timeout`?

EDIT:A second thought is to use the ulimit command instead of timeout.I tried the same thing but with ulimit:

```
 (ulimit -t 10 time ./minisat+_64-bit_static opb_clauses.txt ) 2>>../measures.txt
```

but this time i don't have any result written to measures.txt

Answer (score 2):

There must be something up with your environment because when I try the same example I get the expected results. For example:

```
# command #1
$ (time echo "hi") 2>> measures.txt
hi

$ cat measures.txt 

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

# command #2
$ (timeout 1s time echo "hi") 2>> measures.txt
hi

$ cat measures.txt 

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.05elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 552maxresident)k
56inputs+0outputs (1major+173minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Instead of structuring your command as 2 separate calls why not do it like so:

```
(
 time ./minisat+_64-bit_static opb_clauses.txt
 timeout 1s time ./minisat+_64-bit_static opb_clauses.txt
) 2>>../measures.txt
```

Comment: i tried to run it in 2 commands but i got a segmentation fault.Is it ok to have both commands in ()?

Comment: also,i try your first example(echo "hi"etc) and i got the same result as my other results,so you must be right that is something with my environment.I am in Cent0S.Any ideas of solving this issue?

Comment: @Dchris - yes you can have both commands inside the `()`. The first command will run, once it's done, the second command will then run. The `()` are called command groups, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Grouping_Statements.